# Composer generates incorrectly capitalized namespaces

Tags: php, json, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

When pulling in a self-made composer package, the files that get pulled in have different namespace capitalization than the the source code.

---

**The package source code on GitHub**

Source [composer.json](http://github.com/bsapaka/metattribute/blob/master/composer.json) code:

```
"name": "bsapaka/metattribute",
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Bsapaka\\Metattribute\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

Source [namespace](https://github.com/bsapaka/metattribute/blob/master/src/Attribute.php):

`namespace Bsapaka\Metattribute;`

---

**The code that appears when pulled into project [from Packagist](http://packagist.org/packages/bsapaka/metattribute)**

The line that composer generates in `autoload_psr4.php`:

```
'bsapaka\\metattribute\\' => array($vendorDir . '/bsapaka/metattribute/src'),
```

The namespace appearing in the vendor files:

`namespace bsapaka\Metattribute;`

The exception when trying to use it:

> Class 'bsapaka\Metattribute\AttributeList' not found

---

I have tried changing the source code capitalizations. All upper case, all lower case, one upper one lower, etc. Each time, the psr4 path and the class namespaces are never the same, and the exception persists.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled down a [copy of your library](https://github.com/bsapaka/metattribute/commit/736a4a900877492aa6a7f1a4625ffb19dd1111c8) and created a PHPUnit test. I could not reproduce your problem. It looks like you got it resolved? You are now using `namespace Bsapaka\Metattribute`.

In `Tests\AttributeTest.php`:

```
<?php

class AttributeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testName()
    {
        $attribute = new \Bsapaka\Metattribute\Attribute("Elvis");
        $this->assertEquals("Elvis", $attribute->getName());
    }
}
```

To get the above to work, `composer.json` now includes:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
}
```

And launched via: `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/AttributeTest.php`

Comment: Still problems on my end... did you pull in via composer?

Comment: Yes. I had to require `"bsapaka/matattribute": "dev-master"` since it has your corrected namespace. v1.0.0 is still broken :)